# Is it possible to send data from client (browser) to puppeteer?

Tags: phantomjs, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have been created a server side render by phantomjs before like this.

**client side**

```
// when all client ajax request and page render finished
window.callPhantom('page.done')

// when page not found
window.callPhantom('page.fail')
```

**server side**

```
page.onCallback = function(status) {
  // when page render finished
  if(status == 'page.done') {
    // start render
  }

  // when page not found
  else {
    // response 404 page not found
  }
}
```

And I wanna change from phantomjs to chrome puppeteer now.

How can I to pass data from the client side (browser) to server(puppeteer) after all client ajax request is finished (like phantomjs [callPhantom](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html)).

Is it possible do that by using chrome puppeteer?

Comment: Do you want to pass back data from the target page or to render it? I think there might be two different questions here.

Comment: Yes, I need pass data from target page to puppeteer , cuz server need to check page is valid or not found in this way.

Comment: When server get this pass data event, puppeteer will start to render this page, just like use PhantomJS "callPhantom" method

Comment: Please update your question with demo code of how you're using `callPhantom` now, I'm not quite sure I get your explanation.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have updated my question yet.

Comment: How do you decide that all client ajax request are finished?

Comment: I use js "Promise" packaging Ajax request. And decide all request finished by "await".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had face the same problem as you, this is the solution what I got:

You can use the function [page.exposeFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunctionahttps://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction).

It's going to bind a function into the page `window`, so you can just evaluate that function in the client side to do something in the `Node` side.

There's an example in the documentation.

I hope this can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...args)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to pass data to the page. This example passes a selector string to the page for evaluation:

```js
(async() => {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  page.on('console', msg => {
    for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
      console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
  });

  await page.goto('https://google.com/')
  await page.evaluate(selector => {
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    console.log(el.src)
  }, 'img#hplogo');

  await browser.close()
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't describe enough detail.

And I updated my question yet.

I wanna pass data from client(browser) to server(puppeteer).